# Description list with right alignment of labels

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, enumitem, description

I want a description list that looks like the following:

```
          Name | Joel Spolsky
       Address | Some address
                 Some zipcode
     Telephone | +31 123 456
        E-Mail | email@domain.org
Something more | Bashing latex in- 
     elaborate | to submission
```

How would I accomplish this? I've tried using the enumitem package but it doesn't want to align the labels (not the items) to the right as in the above example. When using the multiline style option items either overlap or bump into eachother.

I'm trying to create something like this:

[image]

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setdescription{style=multiline,topsep=10pt,leftmargin=5cm,font=\normalfont}

\section{Experience}
\begin{description}
  \item[Data] 2011 - heden (20 weken) 
  \item[Beroep of functie] Software Developer
  \item[Voornaamste werkzaamheden en verantwoordelijkheden] Software ontwikkeling 
  \item[Naam en adres van de werkgever] Multicast Automatisering B.V. 
  \item[Soort onderneming of sector] Informatie Communicatie Technologie (ICT)
\end{description}
```

Comment: It seems you are looking for a `\tabular` environment with columns `\begin{tabular}{r|l}`.

Comment: When you say you've tried the `enumitem` package, what have you tried? Elaborate on how it hasn't worked...

Comment: I will be using tabular as Marco suggested but I thought description lists were semantically more correct to use in this context.

Comment: The problem with using a `tabular` environment for this is that it does not break across pages. Consequently, it's easier to stick to a list environment that allows this without trouble.

Comment: The updated URL of the example document seems to be http://europassd.cedefop.europa.eu/img/dynamic/c1477/type.FileContent.file/CVExamples2_nl_NL.pdf

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `enumitem` package does not feature a `parright` alignment option, but (somewhat to my surprise) it was rather easy to create (as a carbon copy of the existing `parleft` option).

EDIT: Peter Grill pointed out `\SetLabelAlign` in a comment, and this actually results in superior spacing.

EDIT 2: The alternative version is only recommended if you have an old version of `enumitem` -- hat tip to Alan Munn.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

% Variant A
% \makeatletter
% \def\enit@align@parright{%
%   \def\enit@align##1{%
%     \nobreak
%     \strut\smash{\parbox[t]\labelwidth{\raggedleft##1}}}}
% \makeatother

% Variant B with superior spacing -- thanks to Peter Grill
\SetLabelAlign{parright}{\parbox[t]{\labelwidth}{\raggedleft#1}}

\setlist[description]{style=multiline,topsep=10pt,leftmargin=5cm,font=\normalfont,%
    align=parright}

\begin{document}

\section{Experience}
\begin{description}
  \item[Data] 2011 - heden (20 weken) 
  \item[Beroep of functie] Software Developer
  \item[Voornaamste werkzaamheden en verantwoordelijkheden] Software ontwikkeling 
  \item[Naam en adres van de werkgever] Multicast Automatisering B.V. 
  \item[Soort onderneming of sector] Informatie Communicatie Technologie (ICT)
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could also just use `\SetLabelAlign{parright}{\parbox[t]{\labelwidth}{\raggedleft#1}}` with the latest released version on `enumitem`.

Comment: I've tried to use the above but it doesn't seem to work? Labels are not right-aligned. Or is it me?

Comment: @Dennis: Try to replace `\setlist[description]` with `\setdescription` -- this might (!) work for older `enumitem` versions.

Comment: @lockstep \setdescription will compile the document, but the results are actually the same as my example.

Comment: @Dennis: Just to be sure: You don't see a difference between `align=parright` and `align=parleft`? If so, I'm out of my depth.

Comment: @lockstep: Nope. Sorry.

Comment: @PeterGrill you should post this as a solution. (It gets the spacing nicer than in lockstep's solution.)

Comment: @Alan: I edited my answer because I also noted the superior spacing. Should I refrain from using Peter Grill's suggestion (even with proper attribution)?

Comment: @AlanMunn: Thanks, but since the solution was very similar to this one, I did not feel it warranted a separate answer.

Comment: @lockstep: Its fine to include it as you have done.

Comment: @PeterGrill: I hope to return the favour soon.

Comment: @lockstep No, of course not. :-) You might want to mention that the alternative version is only recommended if you have an old version of `enumitem`.

Comment: Awesome work guys. Thanks everyone! Especially lockstep and Peter Grill.

Comment: I forgot to update my MacTex distribution. Which contained an older version of the enumitem package. This is why the provided answer by lockstep didn't work at first. Run the TexLive Utility to update all packages.

Comment: Note there is a missing `\smash` in `parright`. Compare its definition with that of `parleft` in the docs.

Comment: @JavierBezos Please feel free to correct my error, i.e., edit the missing `\smash` in.