# How to align description item labels on the right?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, description

I have seen [description-list-with-right-alignment-of-labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33334/description-list-with-right-alignment-of-labels) that explains, how to align description labels on the right. However the presented solution sets the lengths globally whereas I look for a local solution, meaning to specify the width for each environment separately. Is there a way telling each description environment what the broadest item is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\SetLabelAlign{parright}{\parbox[t]{\labelwidth}{\raggedleft#1}}

\setlist[description]{style=multiline,topsep=10pt,leftmargin=5cm,font=\textbf,align=parright}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item[aaa] some text
\item[bbbbbb] some more text
\item[ccccccccc] and some text
\end{description}


\begin{description}
\item[aaaaaaa] some text
\item[bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb] some more text
\item[ccccccccccccccccccccccc] and some text
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't have time to explain the exact details, so here's a short note. You can define an environment that uses the `list` environment to typeset the `description` list. Let the environment take an option that takes the item with the maximum width. Use it to set the `\labelwidth`at the start of the environment (using the style for the labels). You also have to redefine `\makeitem`, which should use the label, and set it in the right style, right justified in an `\hbox to \labelwidth` (or equivalent). It's not too much work, but keep track of how the `list` environment positions the labels.

Comment: You are aware that `enumitem` allows you to set parameters both globally (as in your MWE) and locally (as in `\begin{description}[style=...]`)?

Comment: Apologies: `\makeitem` should be `\makelabel`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `\widthof{}` from [the `calc` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/calc) to compute the correct width for the `labelwidth` on a per `description` list to obtain:

[image]

The parameter passed to the `\widthof{}` should be the widest element in the `description` list and also note that since the label is set in bold font, we need to ensure that the measurements are done with `\bfseries` applied:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\SetLabelAlign{parright}{\parbox[t]{\labelwidth}{\raggedleft#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}[labelwidth=\widthof{\bfseries ccccccccc},align=parright]
    \item[aaa]       some text
    \item[bbbbbb]    some more text
    \item[ccccccccc] and some text
\end{description}

\begin{description}[labelwidth=\widthof{\bfseries ccccccccccccccccccccccc},align=parright]
    \item[aaaaaaa]                 some text
    \item[bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb]         some more text
    \item[ccccccccccccccccccccccc] and some text
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Furthermore, if the label is always set to the widest one, then boxing it in a parbox is unnecesary - just use `align=right`. (And I added to the todo list a `widest` for `description`.)

Comment: `\begin{description}[labelwidth=4em,align=parright]` gives this error for me: "Package enumitem: Unknown value 'parright' for key 'align'". I don't know if this was allowable in 2012 when the answer was written; however, it is not valid now. See the documentation at http://www.texnia.com/archive/enumitem.pdf which states: "Three values are possible: left, the default right and parleft"

Comment: @DavidJ.: Did you include the line `\SetLabelAlign{parright}{\parbox[t]{\labelwidth}{\raggedleft#1}}`?

Comment: @PeterGrill whoops, I overlooked that. Thank you.