# spacing in a description list using enumitem

Tags: spacing, lists, enumitem, description

I found [Description list with right alignment of labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33334/description-list-with-right-alignment-of-labels) while looking for a solution for my own problem. I tried to modify the above solution, but there are a few ugly things I don't know what to do about.

1. Using `noitemsep` to remove the space between the items results in different spacing between lines in labelboxes and labelboxes to each other.
2. If the text in the labelbox is too long and therefore a line break needed, then the second line of the text belonging to the label starts after the labelbox, not in the second line.

[image]

Here is the corresponding code:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{enumitem}  
\SetLabelAlign{parright}{\parbox[t]{\labelwidth}{\raggedleft#1}}
\setlist[description]{style=multiline,leftmargin=3.5cm, align=parright,noitemsep}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
  \item[here is a long long label] text
  \item[here is a long long label]  and here a long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long text
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

What can/should I do?

Comment: Why do you want to use `noitemsep` if you want spacing between the items?

Comment: I dont want to have space between items, but rather, if there is one, to be identical. Like in the picture: the space between the first and the second labelbox is smaller then the space between the two lines inside of the labelbox.   
And, the big space in the second textbox is annoying me.

Answer (score 4):

Here is:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{enumitem}  
\SetLabelAlign{parright}{\strut\smash{\parbox[t]{\labelwidth}{\raggedleft#1}}}
\setlist[description]{style=multiline,leftmargin=3.5cm, align=parright,noitemsep}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
  \item[here is a long long label] text\\\mbox{}
  \item[here is a long long label]  and here a long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long text
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Note (1) I've added a `\smash` to the label, and (2) I've added an empty line by hand to the first item, to avoid the problem shown in the manual related to multiline labels.

Comment: ok, but if you add these lines: >> \item[short] short text \\\mbox{}   \item[short] short text \\\mbox{} << there will be again a blank line between these lines.

Comment: Of course, you should add a blank line only if the label has more lines than the item body.

Answer (score 0):

and with a possible pagebreak

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{ltablex}% available from http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ltablex
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} >{\bfseries\raggedleft}p{0.25\linewidth} X @{}}
here is a long long label & text \\
here is a long long label & and here a long long long long long long long long long
long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long 
long long long long text\\
\pagebreak
here is a long long label & and here a long long long long long long long long long 
long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long 
long long long long text
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: well, the problem is, that the text could also be as long as half of a page, and so leaving a lot of free and unused space, as I can't have a page break in a pbox...

Comment: if you have not too many of thos description list, it can be done by hand ...

Comment: I got 18-30 of those, with each 13 items, and one of these items contains of a really long text, like I said, half a page. And the problem with such a long pbox is, that I can't have a pagebreak in it...

Comment: you can insert it by hand with `\parfillskip=0pt\\` in a tabular line

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution I'm using right now:

```
\setlist[description]{style=multiline,leftmargin=3.7cm,parsep=6px}
```

then using a description list, and, if the label is too long, I'm just filling the textbox with `\\ \hspace*{\fill}`, works pretty fine for me :-)