# right description list LaTeX beamer

Tags: beamer, spacing, horizontal-alignment, lists, description

How to do right align a description list using beamer?

```
      Name | Joel Spolsky
   Address | Some address
```

Using the enumitem package as suggested in 
[Description list with right alignment of labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33334/description-list-with-right-alignment-of-labels) does not seem to work with the beamer package

Answer (score 50, accepted):

With `beamer` package, the `description` environment can use an optional argument: a text to fix the maximum width of terms (cf. section **12.1 "Itemizations, Enumerations, and Descriptions"**, p.113 of beamer guide v3.26).

Example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=cyan!10}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{description}[Other description]
  \item[Name] Joel Spolsky
  \item[Address] Some address  
  \item[Other description] Some description
  \end{description}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## How to align items to the left

By default, items are aligned to the right. To align items to the the left :

- in your preamble, define the *predefined option*  `align left` for the template `description item`:

  ```
   \defbeamertemplate{description item}{align left}{\insertdescriptionitem\hfill}
  ```
- apply this *prefined option* before a description list:

  ```
   \setbeamertemplate{description item}[align left]
  ```

Example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=gray!5}
\defbeamertemplate{description item}{align left}{\insertdescriptionitem\hfill}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{block}{Default}
    \setbeamertemplate{description item}[default]
    \begin{description}[Other description]
    \item[Name] Joel Spolsky
    \item[Address] Some address  
    \item[Other description] Some description
    \end{description}
  \end{block}
  \begin{block}{Align left}
    \setbeamertemplate{description item}[align left]
    \begin{description}[Other description]
    \item[Name] Joel Spolsky
    \item[Address] Some address  
    \item[Other description] Some description
    \end{description}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1): Good solution. Is there any way to align `items` to left?

Comment: @MYaseen208 I edited my answer.

Comment: Simply Awesome!!! I Opened the bounty and will reward you soon. Thanks

Comment: Can you guide me how to use `\setbeamertemplate{description item}[align left]` globally? Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208 To change alignment globally, insert this line before your first frame (or in your preamble).

Comment: I had to invert \descriptionitem and \hfill so it became:
\defbeamertemplate{description item}{align left}{\hfill\insertdescriptionitem}

Comment: @Daniel With `\hfill\insertdescriptionitem`, you can't align to the left...

Comment: For some reason, my `description` environments were all shifted to the right, like with some additional margin. Thanks to this answer, I got the idea to use the optional argument `[~]` and everything got back to the normal left alignment of the slides as it should.