# Description Environment options in LyX

Tags: beamer, lyx, enumitem, description

The code given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/67740/4821) can be used to adjust the `items` and `text` in `description` environment. I wonder how to use these options `[leftmargin=!,labelwidth=\widthof{\bfseries The longest label}]` with `beamer` in `LyX`. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it!!!

1. Add   `\defbeamertemplate{description item}{align left}{\insertdescriptionitem\hfill}`  in *preamble*.
2. Use `description` environment in `LyX`.
3. Add `\setbeamertemplate{description item}[align left]` in ERT before the `description` environment in `LyX`.
4. Right click the *first* entry in the list, choose *Insert Longest label*.
5. Add an ERT in the *opt* box, with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.
6. Write `The longest label` in the ERT.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround is to not use a list at all, but a table where the first column is an `l` column, and the second is a `p` column. Add a table with Insert --> Table, or the corresponding button on the toolbar, remove all horizontal and vertical lines, and make it two columns. Right click a cell in the second column, and choose More --> Settings. Set the width to a specific value, this will allow for line breaking in the second column. Make the first column left aligned.

---

#### Original answer -- doesn't work for `beamer`

1. Add the *Customisable lists (enumitem)* module, in Document --> Settings --> Modules.
2. To use  `\widthof` you need to load the `calc` package, so in Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble add

   ```
   \usepackage{calc}
   ```
3. Right click the *first* entry in the list, choose *Insert short title*.
4. Add an ERT in the *opt* box, with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.
5. Write `leftmargin=!,labelwidth=\widthof{\bfseries The longest label}` in the ERT.

You can also define global settings for all `description` lists, as I mention in my answer to [Description-like environment with fixed labels width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33817/description-like-environment-with-fixed-labels-width/33818#33818)

Comment: Thanks @Torbjorn for your answer. Something going weird with me today. I'm using beamer and couldn't add Customisable lists (enumitem) module. Then I tried \usepackage{enumitem} which again not working. Any idea!!!

Comment: @MYaseen208 No, `enumitem` isn't compatible with `beamer`, sorry. I don't have any alternative at the moment.

Comment: One possibility is to use `\usedescriptionitemofwidthas{The longest label}`. This is partial solution which adjust the text but doesn't align the `items`.

Comment: [This](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95977/4821) is also helpful.

Comment: Thanks @Torbjorn for your help. I figure out the problem. See my answer.