# Indenting Text in Beamer

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment

I am attempting to indent text, as below.
[image]

To get the alignment right (and it's far from perfect right now), I've been using trial and error with a linebreak `\\` and `\hspace{3.1cm}`. Is there a legitimate way to get the results in the image above?

As a minimum working example, I have

```
    \documentclass[12pt,mathserif]{beamer} 
    \usetheme{Berkeley}
    \usecolortheme{dove}
    \useinnertheme{default}
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[default]
    \setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]

    \beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
    \setbeamerfont{footline}{size=\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont}
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]

    \begin{document}
    \frame{\frametitle{Detecting MWEs in Typed Text}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item $\mathbf{Assumption \;1}$: MWEs have unique prosodic\\
        \hspace{3.1cm}characteristics
    \item $\mathbf{Assumption \;2}$: KD is the reflection of prosody in\\
        \hspace{3.1cm}typing
    \item $\mathbf{Conclusion}$: \hspace{0.5cm}MWEs should be uniquely\\
        \hspace{3.1cm}characterized in typing
    \end{itemize}
    }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163643/description-environment-options-in-lyx/ I guess, though that is for LyX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such an alignment is easy when using a `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{@{\textbullet~}l@{\ }p{2in}}
  \bfseries Assumption 1: & MWEs have unique prosodic characteristics \\
  \bfseries Assumption 2: & KD is the reflection of prosody in typing \\
  \bfseries Conclusion:   & MWEs should be uniquely characterized in typing
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If you don't want to measure the right column width (currently fixed at `2in`), then you can use a [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) instead. Also, [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) could be used to aid in formatting the first column to `\bfseries` automatically, if needed. Here's an example incorporating both *with* a raggedright second column:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\usepackage{array,tabularx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{array,tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{\textbullet~}>{\bfseries}l@{\ }>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X@{}}
  Assumption 1: & MWEs have unique prosodic characteristics \\
  Assumption 2: & KD is the reflection of prosody in typing \\
  Conclusion:   & MWEs should be uniquely characterized in typing
\end{tabularx}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Any way to make it not break a word?

Comment: @Adam_G: I've added a [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) and [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) example to the answer. It also allows for using `\raggedright` in the last column, which doesn't hyphenate.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the method described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163733/586, changing to a `description` environment.

```
\documentclass[12pt,mathserif]{beamer} 
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usecolortheme{dove}
\useinnertheme{default}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamerfont{footline}{size=\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]

% new additions
\defbeamertemplate{description item}{align left}{$\blacktriangleright$ \bfseries\insertdescriptionitem\hfill}
\setbeamertemplate{description item}[align left]

\begin{document}
\frame{\frametitle{Detecting MWEs in Typed Text}
\begin{description}[Assumption 2:]
\item [Assumption 1:] MWEs have unique prosodic
characteristics
\item [Assumption 2:] KD is the reflection of prosody in
typing
\item [Conclusion:] MWEs should be uniquely
characterized in typing
\end{description}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There could be better ways, but here is one way with a stack.  I used `\bullet` because I didn't know the name of the right-pointing triangle symbol.  Also, for some reason, I had to change the stacking end-of-line (EOL) symbol fromt he default `\\` to something else, in this case `\#`.  The stacktabbedgap sets the gap between the columns.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\newcommand\pparbox[2]{\protect\parbox[t]{#1}{#2\strut}}
\setstacktabbedgap{1ex}
\setstackEOL{\#}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\tabbedShortstack[l]{
 \bfseries $\bullet$ Assumption 1: & \pparbox{2in}{%
    MWEs have unique prosodic characteristics}\#
 \bfseries $\bullet$ Assumption 2: & \pparbox{2in}{%
    KD is the reflection of prosody in typing}\#
 \bfseries $\bullet$ Conclusion: & \pparbox{2in}{%
    MWEs should be uniquely characterized in typing}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you were going to use the technique often, much of the syntax could be put into macros:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\newcommand\pparbox[2]{\protect\parbox[t]{#1}{#2\strut}}
\def\secondcolwidth{2in}%DEFAULT
\newcommand\firstcol[1]{\bfseries$\bullet$ #1:}
\newcommand\secondcol[1]{\pparbox{\secondcolwidth}{#1}}
\setstacktabbedgap{1ex}
\setstackEOL{\#}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\def\secondcolwidth{2in}
\tabbedShortstack[l]{
 \firstcol{Assumption 1} & \secondcol{MWEs have unique prosodic characteristics}\#
 \firstcol{Assumption 2} & \secondcol{KD is the reflection of prosody in typing}\#
 \firstcol{Conclusion}   & \secondcol{MWEs should be uniquely characterized in typing}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```