# Aligning numbers in a list

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists

I am trying to align the numbers in a list as in the picture below. Currently when I do it the (i) and (ii) are aligned on the left just by starting a new line of code, but how do I get them to be aligned on the right?

[image]

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33334/description-list-with-right-alignment-of-labels could be relevant.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it turns out that this question is on MathJax actually (see the comments to the answer by Mico,please!)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you load the `enumitem` package and define a dedicated enumerate-like list environment that uses lowercase-roman letters.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{romanenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[romanenum]{label=(\roman*)} % roman numerals, encased in parentheses

\begin{document}
\begin{romanenum}
\item For any natural number \dots
\item If $a,b,c,d\in M$, \dots
\end{romanenum}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am not writing the Latex in a document, so I don't think the new list and set list is going to work for me. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: @user19405892: What do you mean you're not writing LaTeX in a document? Do you use `ConTeXt` or `TeX`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It is like Tex and used for writing Latex for a blog. But I can't use document class and things like that for some reason.

Comment: @user19405892: It seems that your question is totally off-topic here -- looks like MathJax stuff then -- you should have provided this information in your question :-(

Comment: @user19405892 - Should we close this posting as being off-topic for this site?

Comment: @Mico If you don't see any way of doing the code you did in MathJax then yes.

Comment: @user19405892 - TeX.SE is definitely not a MathJax site. I've voted to close the posting.