# Enumitem: Right align the label

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumitem

I am trying to use the `enumitem` package to create the following

```
             Farmer: It is a hard day today. The sun is
                     burning and we still haven't brought
                     in all the crop.
 Farmer's Neighbour: Yes, it will be a long day!
             Farmer: ...
```

I want the label to be right aligned and the text to wrap at that point too.

[I tried the following solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33334/description-list-with-right-alignment-of-labels) (`\SetLabelAlign{parright}{\parbox[t]{\labelwidth}{\raggedleft#1}}`, but then my label and text overlap.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\SetLabelAlign{parright}{\parbox[t]{\labelwidth}{\raggedleft#1}}
\setlist[enumerate]{
  align=parright, 
  leftmargin=0pt, 
  labelindent=20pt,
  listparindent=40pt, 
  labelwidth=20pt, 
  itemindent=!
 }

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=Farmer:]
  \item It is a hard day today. The sun is burning and we still haven't brought in all the crop.
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[label=Farmer's Neigbour:]
   \item Yes, it will be a long day!
 \end{enumerate}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Why are you using an `enumerate` list when you want a `description` type list?

Comment: Just try `align=left`, It should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a list-by-list basis, you can use the options below between `[..]`. Notice that calc package is required to measure the width of the widest label automatically. If you need the same settings for all description lists, use this command

```
\setlist[description]{style=multiline, labelwidth=\widthof{Farmer's Neigbour: },%
                    font=\normalfont, leftmargin=\labelwidth, align=right}
```

in preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[style=multiline, labelwidth=\widthof{Farmer's Neigbour: },%
                    font=\normalfont, leftmargin=\labelwidth, align=right]
\item[Farmer:] It is a hard day today. The sun is burning and we still haven't brought in all the crop.
\item[Farmer's Neigbour:] Yes, it will be a long day!
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to keep the regular description list, you can define a new list, e.g. `\newlist{dialogue}{description}{1}` and then use `\setlist[dialogue]{style=multiline, labelwidth=\widthof{Farmer's Neigbour: },font=\normalfont, leftmargin=\labelwidth, align=right}`

Comment: Is there a way to dynamically update `\widthof{Farmer's Neighbour:}? So the list can be reused?

Comment: This will require more work, in such a case, a `longtable` or just a `tabular` may be preferred.

Comment: @Jo- Not completely automatic, but if you define a new list, then for any particular instance of that environment you can just specify a new value for the `labelwidth`, e.g. `\begin{dialogue}[labelwidth=\widthof{Farmer's son: }]`.